# RESTful Web Services connecting to database, Entity Manager is null

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, netbeans, sql-server-2012

I'm creating a RESTful webservice that interacts with a database using NetBeans 8.0, Java EE 7, Tomcat 8.0.12, Maven, and Microsoft SQL Server 2012.  I used NetBeans 'RESTful Web Services from Entity Classes' feature in order to create the necessary files to connect and interact with a database. When I test the url that's supposed to return everything in a table, I get a null pointer exception.

I looked at line 43 of AbstractFacade and found that getEntityManager returns null, thus causing the NullPointerException.  I've searched around and can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and will post more info if needed.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    service.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:43)
    service.TestTableFacadeREST.findAll(TestTableFacadeREST.java:69)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is the persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="com.madejekz_RestTest2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
      <class>com.madejekz.resttest2.TestTable</class>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://IP_ADDRESS_HERE;databaseName=test_ford"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is the AbstractFacade.java:

```
package service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

Finally here is the TestTableFacadeREST.java:

```
package service;

import com.madejekz.resttest2.TestTable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Stateless
@Path("com.madejekz.resttest2.testtable")
public class TestTableFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<TestTable> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.madejekz_RestTest2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public TestTableFacadeREST() {
        super(TestTable.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(TestTable entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") String id, TestTable entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public TestTable find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<TestTable> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<TestTable> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by removing the line:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.madejekz_RestTest2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
```

from the TestTableFacadeREST.java file and adding the line:

```
em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.madejekz_RestTest5_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU").createEntityManager();
```

to the getEntityManager method in the TestTableFacadeREST.java file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the transaction-type to `JTA` in JavaEE environment. So change it to

```
<persistence-unit name="com.madejekz_RestTest2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Please note that `RESOURCE_LOCAL` should be mentioned in `JavaSE` environment.

Comment: Did that, but still having the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Which version of EclipseLink JPA do you use?

Comment: The version of EclipseLink JPA is 2.5.1

Comment: Correction to my previous comment, the version for EclipseLink JPA is 2.1